# WebViewActivity stopped when minimize app

Tags: android, android-studio, webview, android-webview

For my project I have created a WebViewActivity. Everything would seem to work correctly but when I minimize the app and then return my WebViewActivity is closed and the app returns to the previous activity. How can I prevent the WebViewActivity from being closed by minimizing the app? here my code:

```
class WebViewActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_web_view)

    val webView = findViewById<WebView>(R.id.offerWebView)
    webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled= true
    webView.loadUrl(intent.getStringExtra("url"))
}
}
```

and here my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WebView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/offerWebView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="com.android.app">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/flower_classic_ic"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/flower_classic_ic"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    tools:replace="android:theme">
    <activity-alias
        android:name=".launchericons.GreenIconLauncher"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:icon="@mipmap/flower_green_ic"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:targetActivity=".ui.SplashScreenActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity-alias>

    //...
    //other activities
    //...
    <activity
        android:name=".ui.WebViewActivity"
        android:noHistory="true"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
```

Comment: want to see your manifest

Comment: check my update. Thanks

Comment: why are you using `android:noHistory="true"` remove it